# Quick Preg_Replace Question

Tags: php

I wanna preg replace anything inbetween （THIS） those two bracket thingys I want to remove them plus the content inside. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/（.+?）/', '', $string);
```

To clarify:

- the first character is `EF BC 88` represented in UTF-8, which is a "Ideographic left parenthesis"
- the last character is  `EF BC 89` represented in UTF-8, which is a "Ideographic right parenthesis"

These are [east asian punctuation marks](http://lcweb2.loc.gov/diglib/codetables/9.4.html). They are not `7B` - `(` or `7D` - `)`.

Comment: don't you need to escape the left paren?  it signifies the beggining of a backref no?

Comment: @David, that's not a left paren. It's a "（" character.

Comment: Would you not need to escape the brackets too:
`preg_replace('/\（.+?\）/', '', $string);`
Otherwise it would be a grouping would it not?

Comment: @Colin, they are not parathesis. They are a special Unicode character. They are not part of standard regular expression syntax.

Comment: Ah ok. Next to impossible to notice!

Comment: Thanks how about for: £¨ THIS £©  to remove whats inbetween that

Comment: @Arber, same as you do with the punctuation marks. `/£¨.+?£©/`. This last string though looks like an erroneous Unicode decoding.

Comment: Works for me. FYI, `.+?` and `.*` have different greediness and results when these bracket thingies are nested. i.e. preg_replace on " （ A ） B ） " returns " B ） " for the first and "  " for the second.

Comment: @Arber, as I was saying, it's likely the last string is wrongly decoded... The first 2 and the last 2 characters look like they should be only 1 instead of 2, if the decoding was done correctly... Did you copy them from a web page?

Comment: yeah it was from some chinese page my script grabs it from and it ends up being: £¨Feat£© so I am looking to remove the whole thing (including feat but its different for other ones)

Comment: @Arber, in this particular case, `£¨` and `£©` look wrong. It looks like `£¨` shouldn't be `£¨`, but rather something else. Can you open the page in a web browser and select "UTF-8" encoding? What does the string look like after doing that?

Comment: thanks for reminding me the page is encoded in a different encode. I used iconv to convert it to UTF-8 and it fixed the problem godbless :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern  = '/\([^)]*)/';
preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```